# Visual Basic 2010: How can I put the two values in the same row in my database?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

Visual Basic 2010: How can I put the two values in the same row in my database?

Button 1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        rst = opentable("Select * from timesheet", ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer)
        With rst
            .AddNew()
            .Fields("time1").Value = Date.Now
            .Update()
            MsgBox("Time in")
        End With
    End Sub
```

Button 2

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        rst = opentable("Select * from timesheet", ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer)
        With rst
            .AddNew()
            .Fields("time2").Value = Date.Now
            .Update()
            MsgBox("Time Out")
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add more specifics. What two values are you trying to add? Where do you want to add them? In `Button1_Click()`, `Button2_Click()`, or elsewhere? What have you tried? I don't see any attempt to add two values together.

Comment: i meant is to put them in the same row in my database, the two values that i got from clicking those 2 buttons

Comment: Please show the code where you attempt to add the two values together.

Comment: sorry i used the wrong word, i just want to put them together in the same row because if i click the 2nd button it adds onto the next row

Comment: What does `.AddNew()` do?

Comment: Add data to the database?

Comment: Looks like that AddNew() adds a new row to the database (no idea what that second parameter in opentable stands for). At least, for the second button, you should not add a row, but update the one from the first click.